# Skipped 30 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, client

Делал вроде бы всё по инструкции. В Андроид разработке полный аматор, пытаюсь написать первое своё приложение - клиент для сайта. 
Как решить проблему? вроде бы разделяю действия по внутренним классам, все равно ошибка с потоками..

```
package client.adme.ru.websiteparsing;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
private TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    ParseTitle parseTitle = new ParseTitle();
    parseTitle.execute();

    try {
        final HashMap<String, String> hashMap = parseTitle.get();
        final ArrayList<String > arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            arrayList.add(entry.getKey().toString());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String > arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ParseText parseText = new ParseText();
                parseText.execute(hashMap.get(arrayList.get(position)));

                try {
                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setText(parseText.get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}

class ParseText extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String str = " ";

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            Element element = doc.select(".wrap.footer-placeholder").first();
            str = element.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;
    }
}


class ParseTitle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String, String>> {

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HashMap<String , String > hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.adme.ru/").get();
            Elements elements = doc.select(".al-title");

            for (Element element : elements )  {
                Element element1 = element.select("a[href]").first();
                hashMap.put(element.text(), element1.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hashMap;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

метод `parseTitle.get()` вешает главный поток на время, пока не закончится выполнение `parseTitle.execute()`.
Чтобы не вешать главный поток, переопределите у  `ParseTitle` метод `onPostExecute()`. Этот метод будет вызван в главном потоке после завершения метода `doInBackground()`

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую!